# How does the Digi-Clone choose what gun to use?

Tags: borderlands-3

How does the Digi-Clone choose what gun to use?

Its final skill is to use the current, so that's not what happens otherwise...

Is the choice initially random, out of the equipped 2, 3, or 4 guns, and so, if I stuck to 1 gun, it'd always use that one?

Comment: Are you asking about [Double Barrel](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Double_Barrel) passive skill? I haven't played Zane yet, but my instinct would be to just google for skill name and few words like "best weapon". You may find some reddit/steam/official forum posts. Likely this skill and which weapons to use is explained in zane build guides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this wiki page](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Digi-Clone)

> The Digi-Clone is by default equipped with a Dahl assault rifle, and will trigger related challenges and loyalty packages.

So, without Double Barrel, it uses that assault rifle.

Comment: I wonder which of the three modes the clone uses... <https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Challenge#General_Challenges_8>

Comment: Well, just took off all my gear and let the Clone kill something. Seems to be the Going Loud challenge that updated, a.k.a it uses Full-auto. Yep, almost 20 kills, and all contributing to Going Loud.